# TwitterBootstrapMvc suddenly returns Object not set to an instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have [TwitterBootstrapMvc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc) installed in my web project. It's really helpful and is working fine in my development environment. Since yesterday it does not work on my Azure site though and I can't figure out why. As soon as I have a TwitterBootstrapMvc extension in a view like:

```
 @Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.TaskCreateTitle).Size(InputSize.XLarge).Placeholder().Label()
```

I get an error saying that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I installed it via nuget. Apparently Bootstrap isn't initialized but I don't understand is why it runs fine locally but not in Azure. Can anyone help me to look in the right direction on where I could make sure it is initalized.

Comment: On which object do you have the exception?

Comment: Its on the Bootstrap() object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug which will be corrected in the next version.

Comment: What version are you using? I plan to start using TwitterBootstrapMVC tonight, so I obviously don't want to face this issue!

Answer (score 0):

How did u deploy to azure? Did u set all the dependencies to copy to local? I think some bootstrap mvc depedencies are missing.

Comment: Yes, the TwitterBootstrap.MVC.dll is in the bin on Azure. It is set to Copy Local